# How to extend the "album" model to return other objects from the database?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

The ZF2 user guide explains how to [set up and query the database using the Table Data Gateway pattern](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable).

I wonder what would be the best approach to extend this design with another table, let's say "tracks".

It's easy to just copy the existing method of using the serviceManager to create a new tableGateway and object for the tracks table and use a controller to get tracks for a specific album. But it feels wrong to do it that way.

I'm thinking about extending the Album model with a method that returns the tracks for this specific album. But to do so I'd have to use the tracks tableGateway inside the Album model - and I'm not sure how to set that up.

Using the serviceManager inside the model to get access to the track gateway and object seems wrong. Or do I inject them into the object somehow?

What is the preferred way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the point where you are saying "it feels wrong to do it that way" you should stop thinking about the solution and reason about the problem. Your problem might be that you don't know your problem enough to pick a solution.

When you do software design, you shouldn't ask yourself to make arbitrary design choices. Instead, you must identity your key requirements and pick the simplest solution that fill these requirements.

Here, I would advise you to stick to the simplest solution: having a completely different tableGateway and business object, not linked at all to the album business object.

BUT since you are using a ZF2 guide, you clearly want to learn more about ZF2. This is one of your design requirement so I would advise you to use ZF2 tools to solve your problem in many different ways. 
You can use the service manager factories and abstract factories, build another module, use a different storage, etc.